# pdf to xml or html or text formats

Tags: c#, xml, perl, pdf

I have a pdf document, that have information, presented in tables.

How can i convert it to html or xml or text to read this tables like text?

Is there any good programs?

Both Perl-modules and .Net-Classes are good. Maybe good executable console application?

```
  XMLFile = new PDFTOXML('file.pdf');
  String[] StrArray = XMLFile.getText();
```

Something like this. 
Best way is ability to get tables from xml.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/pdf2text.aspx

Comment: I didn't -1 this, but SO is not a place to dump links. It's a place to provide answers to questions, and a naked link with no answer is not an answer. That link could be wrong or it could disappear at some point in the future. Provide your own answer for a question and you won't get downvoted. See also [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72000/should-there-be-a-policy-about-one-link-only-answers) for further details.